# MinGW external libraries location

Tags: c

I'm running MinGW for the first time and I have trouble understanding where to put the external packages like the *gsl* library.

I'm showing first the program that I'm trying to run (it's in `C:\Projects\C\`)

```
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double bottom_tail = gsl_cdf_gaussian_P(-1.96, 1);
    printf("A between [-1.96, 1.96]: %f\n", 1 - 2 * bottom_tail);
    return 0;
}
```

this example is from the book `21st Century C`

I've installed correctly `pkg-config` in order to obtain the flags for the compiler automatically. This is my makefile

```
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -O3
LDLIBS= `pkg-config --libs gsl`
CC=gcc

program:
```

I've downloaded the gsl library and put it in c:\gsl, and set `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to this location (where the `.pc` file is)

just running the command `pkg-config --libs gsl` I get the correct flags, but the `make` command crashes, telling me that

```
>>#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h> No such file or directory
```

now I'm guessing that the install location is bad, but where should i put it?

Comment: `pkg-config --libs gsl` gets you linker flags, like where the *library* is... but your error comes from not finding *headers*.  Try adding `pkg-config --cflags gsl` to your CFLAGS

Comment: It may be worth having a read of [HOWTO Specify the Location of Libraries for use with MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW) and [HOWTO Specify the Header File Include Path for use with MinGW Compilers](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO), particularly the parts about locally installed external libraries.